# Why is a common ancestor needed in a 3 way merge commit?

Tags: git

I'm reading [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> In this case, Git does a simple three-way merge, using the two
>   snapshots pointed to by the branch tips and the common ancestor of the
>   two.

[image: 3-way]

> Three snapshots used in a typical merge. Figure 3-16. Three snapshots
>   used in a typical merge Instead of just moving the branch pointer
>   forward, Git creates a new snapshot that results from this three-way
>   merge and automatically creates a new commit that points to it. This
>   is referred to as a merge commit, and is special in that it has more
>   than one parent.

The two tips make sense... but why do you need the common ancestor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git needs to know what changed in each branch, so let us say that `master` change file A, and `iss53` changed file B. Without finding the common ancestor, Git would only know that both files A and B are different in the tips, but not which version of A and B to pick.

By comparing the tips to the common ancestor, Git can reliably see that A has not changed for `iss53`, and therefore uses `master`'s version of A, and vice versa for B.

Of course thing get more complicated when the same file is modified by both branches, but this should clarify things.

Answer (score 3):

The common ancestor requirement should be clearer if you review what a [three-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)#Three-way_merge) actually is.

Using the node labels in your diagram, suppose your repo has a file `foo`.

In commit `C2` (the common ancestor), `foo` contains:

```
a
b
c
```

In commit `C4`, `foo` is changed to:

```
aa
b
c
```

In commit `C5`, `foo` is changed to:

```
a
b
cc
```

Merging `C4` and `C5` should have no conflicts, resulting in:

```
aa
b
cc
```

Taking line 1 as an example, without looking at the common ancestor, Git would only know that this line is different between commits `C4` and `C5`, but not which version (`a` or `aa`) should be kept in the merge result, so Git would have to mark that as a merge conflict. To resolve the conflict, the user would have to compare `foo` as it appears in the common ancestor to `foo` as it appears in `C4` and `C5`. Since line 1 was changed in only one of those commits (`C4`), the change (`aa`) should be kept. By taking the common ancestor into account, Git can do this step automatically.

If `C5` had also changed line 1 (say, to `aaaa`), then Git wouldn't know which version would be best to keep. This would result in a merge conflict that the user would need to resolve manually.

Comment: Let's say that the common ancestor is needed to minimise "conflicts" which can be automatically solved by Git during the merge. Good answer! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is because git does not merge tip-to-tip. Instead it merges branch-to-branch incrementally. Meaning: it merges each commit in each branch separately.

In the example above, git does not merge C4 and C5 directly. Instead it first merges C3 and C4 and then it merges C5 and C4. In order to do this it has to find out where it needs to start merging. Does it start at C0? Does it start as C1? The process of figuring out where to start merging is finding the common ancestor.

Why does git merge this way?

Because it has proven to be the technique that ends up with the least amount of merge conflicts*. Previous source control systems simply do a diff-patch process which tend to produce lots of merge conflicts.

---

*note: In fact the exact algorithm (sequence of merging) git uses is implemented as a plugin so you have the freedom to choose from several algorithms to reduce merge conflicts depending on your workflow.

Comment: No, there is no merge between C3 and C4.  That would be quite pointless, and you can convince yourself of this by introducing a conflict in C3 and removing it in C4.  The merge between C4 and C5 will merge cleanly.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: But C5 ALONE does not contain the changes in C3. It's possible to cherry pick C5 alone without including the changes in C3. When you merge C5 to C4 git will first merge C3 to C4. Yes, if you merge C4 to C5 you do not need to first apply it to C3 but that is not what the diagram shows is it?

Comment: No.  C3 has nothing to do with the result.  C5 is merged with C4, using C2 as a merge base.  C3 is completely ignored, the intermediate commits simply don't matter to `git merge`.